# Is there any way to make BTD6 run better at later levels?

Tags: bloons-td-6

I really enjoy building insane builds and going on as far as I can. But, the game seems to run horrendously at the later levels, to the point where it slows down so much that waves can take like half an hour to finish.

I have a gaming computer, so I don't think it is a problem with my computer being unable to run the game. Is there a way to make the game run smoother? I really want to do more late-game runs, but the game slowing to a crawl as it tries to render projectiles and such makes it quite an annoying task.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, one of the best solutions is selling towers that shoot a lot of projectiles that don't have much power and focusing on a main tower, like a temple.
I think that one of the main causes of the latency is the projectile-blimp collision: if there's both a lot of projectiles and a lot of blimps on screen (like in late game) the game might have to calculate too many collisions, eventually slowing the game down.
*Also, if you have any Alchemist with Acid Pools, move the Alchemist away from the track. For some reason, this upgrade causes a lot of latency.*

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can put your screen in the lowest resolution that the game offers you
a pity that for now they don't offer more options to reduce the quality of the game